# SQL rounding mechanism

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, rounding

I have a following issue with rounding.

SQL Server 2005

```
SELECT ROUND(82.05,1) AS [Round Amount]

Result
[82.10]

SELECT ROUND(82.07,1) AS [Round Amount]
Result
[82.10]
```

How do I customize the rounding function as the below pic?

[image]

Comment: `* 2`, `round`, `/ 2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT ROUND(82.01*2,1)/2 AS [Round Amount]
82.00
SELECT ROUND(82.02*2,1)/2 AS [Round Amount]
82.00
SELECT ROUND(82.03*2,1)/2 AS [Round Amount]
82.05
SELECT ROUND(82.04*2,1)/2 AS [Round Amount]
82.05
SELECT ROUND(82.05*2,1)/2 AS [Round Amount]
82.05
SELECT ROUND(82.06*2,1)/2 AS [Round Amount]
82.05
SELECT ROUND(82.07*2,1)/2 AS [Round Amount]
82.05
SELECT ROUND(82.08*2,1)/2 AS [Round Amount]
82.10
SELECT ROUND(82.09*2,1)/2 AS [Round Amount]
82.10
```

Comment: Yes. Work perfectly.Thank Much